# Double Summation in VBA

Tags: algorithm, vba, sum

I am trying to implement the following algorithm  in VBA:

Please see link: [VT-Micro Algorithm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/avkwowcrel3tj9y/algo.png?dl=0)

Here is my code:

```
s = 7.2
a_inkmhs = 7.2
Total_Fuel = 0
If a_inkmhs >= 0 Then
For i = 0 To 3
    For j = 0 To 3
        Cl = P_coeff(i, j)
        Fuel = Exp(Cl * (s ^ i) * (a_inkmhs ^ j))
     Next j
     Total_Fuel = Total_Fuel + Fuel
Next i
Else
 For i = 0 To 3
    For j = 0 To 3
        ML = N_coeff(i, j)
        Fuel = Exp(ML * (s ^ i) * (a_inkmhs ^ j))
     Next j
     Total_Fuel = Total_Fuel + Fuel
Next i
End If
```

Expected Output: 
   0.002338176
I'm getting : 
  3.999006792

Question: 
What could be wrong with my implementation.

Comment: First thing I see is that you test a instead of a_inkmhs in your If, but it is not the cause of your error. In the algo you linked the a is elevated to power j and in your code you set it to power  of i.

Comment: Thank you Vincent. That was an oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice what you calculate is a sum of exponentials instead of a exponential of sums. Also the update `Total_Fuel = Total_Fuel + Fuel` should be inside the inner for-loops since otherwise you won't calculate the double sum correctly. Also as @VincentG mentioned your `If` should test `a_inkmhs` and not `a` (alternatively you could just rename `a_inkmhs` to `a`) and during the summation `a_inkmhs` should be raised to the power `j` and not `i` , that is `a_inkmhs^j`. The code should be:

```
s = 7.2
a_inkmhs = 7.2
Total_Fuel = 0
If a_inkmhs >= 0 Then
For i = 0 To 3
    For j = 0 To 3
        Cl = P_coeff(i, j)
        Fuel = Cl * (s ^ i) * (a_inkmhs ^ j)
        Total_Fuel = Total_Fuel + Fuel
     Next j
Next i
Else
 For i = 0 To 3
    For j = 0 To 3
        ML = N_coeff(i, j)
        Fuel = ML * (s ^ i) * (a_inkmhs ^ j)
        Total_Fuel = Total_Fuel + Fuel
     Next j
Next i
End If
Total_Fuel = Exp(Total_Fuel)
```

Comment: And j must be used instead of i in `(a_inkmhs ^ i)` (so it should be `(a_inkmhs ^ j)`)

Comment: Thank you. The algorithm is used to compute different Measure of effectiveness (MOE), such as fuel, Carbon emissions etc. The m is an index denoting fuel consumption or emission type, such as CO2, HC,
and NOx emissions. m is not an exponential function.